# Increasing height of button as text size increases in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am very new to autolayout and I have been struggling with one thing.

[image]

The `Roll btn` in the `BottomView` - I am trying to increase it's height according to the text size. As you can see, the height of the `textlabel` of btn in increasing, but the `height` of btn is not.

The `constraints` that I have applied:

1)`Horizontallly` and `verticallly` centered in superview

2)`Leading` and `trailing` from superview

3) I tried setting height constraint to `greaterThanEqualTo` a `constant` also. But that didnt work

4)I tried `SizeToFit` also. Didn't work

5)I have set link `lineBreak` as `WordWrap` and `number of lines` in `titleLabel` as 0. Still its not working

Comment: What are the constraints you set on bottomView ?

Comment: No constraints set explicitly. I have put the views in StackView

Answer (score 0):

i used this solution to change height of uilabal dynamically 
you can get this extension to  get height and width of string

```
extension String {
func height(withConstrainedWidth width: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
    let constraintRect = CGSize(width: width, height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude)
    let boundingBox = self.boundingRect(with: constraintRect, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font], context: nil)

    return ceil(boundingBox.height)
}

func width(withConstrainedHeight height: CGFloat, font: UIFont) -> CGFloat {
    let constraintRect = CGSize(width: .greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: height)
    let boundingBox = self.boundingRect(with: constraintRect, options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: font], context: nil)

    return ceil(boundingBox.width)
}
```

}

since you are using storyboard set height and width constant then link them to viewcontroller script

```
YourContrainsHeight.constant = SomeString.height

YourContrainsWidth.constant = SomeString.width
```

Answer (score 0):

When you modify the `.titleLabel` of a `UIButton`, auto-layout doesn't take your changes into account.

To get a properly auto-sizing multi-line button, you need to subclass it and return a valid `.intrinsicContentSize`.

Here is a quick example:

```
@IBDesignable
class MultilineButton: UIButton {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        commonInit()
        setNeedsLayout()
    }

    func commonInit() -> Void {
        self.titleLabel?.numberOfLines = 0
        self.titleLabel?.textAlignment = .center
        self.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 8.0, left: 8.0, bottom: 8.0, right: 8.0)
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        let size = self.titleLabel!.intrinsicContentSize
        return CGSize(width: size.width + contentEdgeInsets.left + contentEdgeInsets.right, height: size.height + contentEdgeInsets.top + contentEdgeInsets.bottom)
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        titleLabel?.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = self.titleLabel!.frame.size.width
    }

}
```

The class is marked `@IBDesignable` so you can use it in Storyboard / Interface Builder get accurate results.

Here's a look (in Storyboard) of 3 instances of this button. First with a short title, so it doesn't need to wrap; next with a title that *does* wrap; and third with a title that has embedded newlines:

[image]

Note that this example explicitly sets the `Content Edge Insets` to 8-pts on all 4 sides. If you want to be able to change that for individual buttons, it will need a little editing.